# Meaning of Group Homomorphism well-defined

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

I am unable to understand the meaning of this example below from paragraph in Group Homomorphism chapter in book Contemporary Abstract Algebra by Gallian:

"When defining a homomorphism from a group in which there are several ways to represent the elements, caution must be exercised to ensure that the correspondence is a function. (The term *well-defined* is often used in this context.) For example, since $3(x+y)=3x+3y$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6$, one might believe that the correspondence $x+\langle3 \rangle$ $ \to 3x$ from $\mathbb{Z}/\langle 3 \rangle$ to $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is a homomorphism. But it is not a function, since $0+\langle3 \rangle$ $=3+\langle3 \rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}/\langle3 \rangle$ but $3 \bullet0 \neq 3\bullet3$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6."$

Comment: Here $a=0+\langle 3\rangle$ and $b=3+\langle 3\rangle$ are the same element of $\Bbb{Z}/\langle 3\rangle$. If $f$ is a function from $\Bbb{Z}/\langle 3\rangle$ to any other set, it follows that $f(a)=f(b)$. Here that fails. Or rather, different ways of writing $a$ give rise to different elements in the range, indicating that you don't have a function. For something to be a homomorphism it has to be a function first.

Comment: When teaching this I use the following analogy. We have a function $f$ from the set of people $\Omega$ to real numbers assigning each person their weight. We also have an equivalence relation $\sim$ of $\Omega$ defined by saying that $a\sim b$ if they share the first name (so "$\sim$" = "namesakes"). But, the function $f$ does not induce a well-defined function from the set of equivalence classes $\Omega/\sim$ to the real numbers, because namesakes occasionally have different weights. For example, my weight is 115 kg. One of our former prime ministers is a namesake of mine.

Comment: (cont'd) But... let's just say the dude has skipped a few meals, and needs to keep heavy stones in his pockets on windy days. Anyway, for us to get a well-defined function in a case where the domain consists of equivalence classes of objects, we need to be careful, if we use a *representative* of an equivalence class in the definition of the function. In that case we must check that the value is independent of the choice of the representative.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen so the function $f$ would be *well-defined* if both the $a\sim b$ have equal weight? $i.e.,$ if $a=b$ then $f(a)=f(b)$

Comment: That's the idea. Teachers are a bit reluctant to write $f(a)$ unless they have first ascertained that $f$ is, indeed, a function. That's why you don't usually see well-definedness discussed that way.